# installed MongoDB but can not use it(errno:111 connection refused.)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i'm a newbie with MongoDB. i installed it using the tutorial at the [official](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat-centos-or-fedora-linux) website.
when i run the command `mongo`, i get:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.4
connecting to: test
2014-10-08T01:40:35.926+0330 warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2014-10-08T01:40:35.927+0330 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:146
exception: connect failed
```

it gives me the version so i have installed mongodb correctly.(right?).

i thought the problem could have something to do with SELinux so i `Disabled` SELinux but it didn't help.
so how what's the problem and how do i know whether i did the installation correctly or not?
in some of SO posts i saw a command `mongod`. whats the difference between `mongod` and `mongo` commands? when i run `mongod` i get:

```
bash: mongod: command not found...  
Similar command is: 'mongo'
```

many thanks for your help and time.

Comment: `mongod` is server, which needs to be running for accessing the DB via `mongo`. Try, go to `mongo` installaion directory (in my case it's in `/usr/bin` dir), and look for `mongod` and run it directly from terminal `/.mongod`, and see if starts up successfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In essential you need to run `mongod` first before you can connect to it with `mongo`.

The difference between the two is that `mongod` starts the database itself, which holds all the data and runs as a deamon (that's the d in `mongod`). The command `mongo` starts the Client to connect to a mongo deamon, via the client you can now interact with your databases and create collections and documents and query them.

Why this distinction is made? This is standard Client server architecture, because you could think of seperating the mongo deamon on a different machine and afterwards connect from a completly different host to it via the mongo client.